# WebSocket Action call Ignored in runtime

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

Hye Geeks. I am coding for a live notification module in my project. I am tyring to call WebSocket Action method from a function to pass the notification data over the connection to the client.
Here's my code..

```
def liveNotification(data: String) = WebSocket.using[JsValue] { implicit request  =>
    val iteratee = Iteratee.ignore[JsValue]
    val enumerator =  Enumerator[JsValue](Json.toJson(data))
    (iteratee,enumerator)
}

def createNotification(notificationTo: BigInteger, notiParams:Tuple5[String,String,BigInteger,BigInteger,BigInteger]) = {       
    val retData = NotificationModel.createNotification(notificationTo,notiParams)
    val strData = write(retData)
    liveNotification(strData)
}
```

Problem is that the 'liveNotification()' call is simply ignored. Please help me with any suggestions that what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to invoke it with a Json value, at least an empty object. The parser will only match against something that it recognizes as Json.

Comment: But my function is taking a 'String' parameter. Since i am not interested in the incoming message i am ignoring the 'Iteratee' and sending the 'data' as a 'JsValue' through the enumerator. The compiler  not gives any error, not even in the runtime there is any error, but the function is not called.